# Check_urdf does not expand macros in Inertial: mass attribute correctly

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(using Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS Kinetic full desktop install and Gazebo7)

Hi, I've been working on a URDF which works half decently in Gazebo & fully in RViz & joint_state_publisher(some links and joints aren't displayed in Gazebo) but fails to pass Model Parsing in check_urdf and urdf_to_graphiz.
I discovered that for some reason both these packages are unable to parse if any attributes of **mass** or **intertia** are specified as xacro:property macros, but parse well if replaced by literals.

How can I try to make these macros work well in both Gazebo and the urdf parsers? Which gits should I be raising issues in?
I checked some commercial well maintained URDF's (Clearpath Robotics Ridgeback & Gazebo-ROS-demos), both face the exact same issues despite running well in Gazebo & RViz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266144/check_urdf-does-not-expand-macros-in-inertial:-mass-attribute-correctly/) by [ParthC](https://answers.ros.org/users/31123/parthc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I discovered that for some reason both these packages are unable to parse if any attributes of mass or intertia are specified as xacro:property macros, but parse well if replaced by literals.

This reads as if you are passing xacro to `check_urdf` and `urdf_to_graphviz`.

As far as I know those two tools only work with URDF, not xacro. So you'll have to first convert from xacro to urdf, and then pass it on to `check_urdf` and friends.

> which works half decently in Gazebo & fully in RViz & joint_state_publisher

This probably works because whatever launch file loads your `robot_description` parameter uses something like the following:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find your_pkg)/some_xacro_file.xacro'" />
```

that converts xacro to urdf and stores the result on the parameter server in one go.

> How can I try to make these macros work well in both Gazebo and the urdf parsers?

That should be clear now.

> Which gits should I be raising issues in? I checked some commercial well maintained URDF's (Clearpath Robotics Ridgeback & Gazebo-ROS-demos), both face the exact same issues despite running well in Gazebo & RViz

I don't think there is actually a problem to report.

Please try converting xacro to urdf and see whether that fixes your issue(s).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ParthC](https://answers.ros.org/users/31123/parthc/) on 2017-07-12**:
Thanks a lot, that fixed my issue!